# Shader attribute mat4 not binding correctly (Opengl ES 2.0 Android)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I have the following shader:

```
protected final static String vertexShaderCode =
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
    "attribute vec2 texCoord;" +
    "attribute mat4 uMVPMatrix;   \n" +

    "varying vec2 vTexCoord;" +

    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
    "  vTexCoord = texCoord;" +
    "}";
```

I want to pass in the mvp matrix as an attribute, however it doesn't seem to be bound correctly. I'm using auto-assigned binding. When I query the attribute locations after linking the program as follows:

```
// program linked previously
GLES20.glUseProgram(program);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
mTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "texCoord");
mtextureSampHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "textureSamp");
mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "uMVPMatrix");
```

The returned handles are:

mTextureHandle: 0

mMVPMatrixHandle: 1

mPositionHandle: 2

However, from the documention here: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml, mMVPMatrixHandle should be assigned 4 consecutive handles, one for each column of the matrix (i.e. mMVPMatrix should have handles 1,2,3,4). This isn't the case and I have no idea why...

As a result, I'm unable to draw anything to the screen. For completeness, I'm attempting to load the matrix as follows:

```
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mMVPMatrixHandle2, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, t1);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mMVPMatrixHandle2 + 1, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, t2);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mMVPMatrixHandle2 + 2, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, t3);        
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mMVPMatrixHandle2 + 3, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, t4);
```

where t1-t4 are buffers that contain the individual rows of the mvp matrix:

```
{
    1.74f, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 2.9f, 0, 0,
    0, 0, -2.414f, -1f,
    -2.088f, 0, -2.66f, 3
}
```

which works when I define uMVPMatrix as a uniform mat4 and load it in with glUniformMatrix4fv.

Comment: Why do you set MVP matrix and texture sampler in attributes? Do you really need this information for each vertex individually?

Comment: Wrt the MVP matrix, it's a 2d game and I'm trying to batch draw my particle effects. Each particle sprite has its own unique location/orientation and thus it's own MVP matrix. Concatenating the MVP matrices into one array (one matrix per vertex), while wasteful, should be significantly faster than a single draw call for each sprite. I could pass in a uniform array of MVP matrices, but I'm afraid of the GPU emulating on software if my explosion has too many particles. The implementation seems like it should be simple but I'm really not sure why it's not binding 4 locations for the matrix.

Comment: when you bind your matrix data, try using &matrixdata[0] instead of matrixdata. I've had a weird scenario where that seemed to help

Comment: I'm programming in Java (Android) so unfortunately pointers aren't the issue. Though I have been using automatic binding. I'll try manual later today and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the issue wasn't with my card, but the phone. When tried on a Samsung Galaxy S2, the attributes were properly assigned and it worked as expected.

The phone in question is the HTC Incredible S, which had an Adreno 205 graphics card. I imagine that there must be an issue with the Opengl implementation on the phone/graphics card. A solution could be to define the matrix as four vec4s in the shader and calculate the position element by element.